# Windows performance monitor similar to, or the same as, iStat Menus on macOS?

Tags: windows, monitoring, network-monitor, system-monitor, gpu-monitor

Bjango iStat Menus for macOS is arguably the best performance monitor available on any operating system. The way it's presented in the Menubar and how it has bus/storage I/O measurements presented and available along with everything else is just extremely useful.

[image: istat menus example]

Is there any such (or similar) tool for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend taking a look at [bashtop](https://github.com/aristocratos/bashtop) and [bpytop](https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop), which are working on all platforms (Mac, Windows and Linux). Here is a [blog post explaining how to get bashtop running on windows 10](https://davemateer.com/2020/05/02/Bashtop-linux-alternative-to-task-manager).

[image: Main bashtop and bpytop UI showing details for a selected process]